# Errors for block matrix multiplification in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a coordinate matrix cmat with 9 million rows and 85K columns.  I would like to perform cmat.T * cmat operations.
I first converted cmat to block matrix bmat:

```
bmat = cmat.toBlockMatrix(1000, 1000)
```

However, I got errors when performing multiply():

```
mtm = bmat.transpose.multiply(bmat)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'multiply'

The Spark version is 2.2.0, scale version is 2.11.8 on DataProc, Google cloud platform.
Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that the result of operation `bmat.transpose` is a function not a `blockMatrix` and therefore has no attribute `multiply`.

You're just missing `()`:

```
mtm = bmat.transpose().multiply(bmat)
```

Comment: oops, that's the problem.  Thank you!