# Feature crossing, Sparse matrix multiplication, Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, sparse-matrix

I am doing a project in spark and need to apply feature crossing in order to work with longitude and latitude. I am currently taking a look into [sparse matrix multiplication](https://medium.com/balabit-unsupervised/scalable-sparse-matrix-multiplication-in-apache-spark-c79e9ffc0703). However since it is made in scala I do not know how to convert it, therefor I googled and found an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881580/pyspark-rdd-sparse-matrix-multiplication-from-scala-to-python) to it.

So for my question, my data is currently a dataframe based on the following code:

```
# Calculate how many buckets needed (Bins)
discretizer_Lat = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=100, inputCol="Start_Lat", outputCol="Start_Lat_disc")
discretizer_Lng = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=100, inputCol="Start_Lng", outputCol="Start_Lng_disc")

# Into categorical values
indexer_cord = [StringIndexer(inputCol=c + "_disc", outputCol=c+"_IDX") for c in ["Start_Lat","Start_Lng"]]

# One-hot 
encoder_cord = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[indexer.getOutputCol() for indexer in indexer_cord], outputCols=["{0}_vec".format(indexer.getOutputCol()) for indexer in indexer_cord])

# TODO: Feature cross between data
pipeline_cord = Pipeline(stages=[discretizer_Lat,discretizer_Lng, *indexer_cord, encoder_cord])
preprocessed_cord = pipeline_cord.fit(df).transform(df)

position = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["Start_Lat_IDX_vec","Start_Lng_IDX_vec"], outputCol="position")

df = position.transform(preprocessed_cord)
```

*preprocessed_cord* contains the dataframe where I have *Start_Lat_IDX_vec* and *Start_Lng_IDX_vec* and a would like to apply feature crossing or in my understanding sparse vector multiplication.

Function I want to use:

```
def coordinateMatrixMultiply(leftmatrix, rightmatrix):
    left  =  leftmatrix.entries.map(lambda e: (e.j, (e.i, e.value)))
    right = rightmatrix.entries.map(lambda e: (e.i, (e.j, e.value)))
    productEntries = left \
        .join(right) \
        .map(lambda e: ((e[1][0][0], e[1][1][0]), (e[1][0][1]*e[1][1][1]))) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) \
        .map(lambda e: (*e[0], e[1]))
    return productEntries
```

**Question:**
How do I send the dataframe as input to calculate a new sparse vector?